# How to include binaries besides the one that will be executed?

Tags: appimage

I have an app that has an entry point binary which needs to be able to call other custom binaries. What do I have to do to get appimage to package those also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy the binaries into the AppDir in the same place they are found in the system. By example, if you want to ship the `cp` command you will copy it into `AppDir/bin/cp`.

This path can by resolved at runtime using the `$APPDIR` environment variable, so you may want to ensure that it's added to the PATH environment at runtime, like this: `export PATH=$APPDIR:/bin:$PATH`

If you're using [appimage-builder](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the path will be properly set by the tool and you only have to include the package that provides the binary in the `AppDir > apt > include` section.

*If the binary is built with your app, just make sure it also being deployed into the AppDir*.

If you're using other tool you will have to create a startup script and set it manually as in the example above.